# Can constraintsWithVisualFormat be used with dynamically generated views?

Tags: ios, constraints

I have a list of tags in my model. I would like to add them as label inside a `tagView` UIView as subviews.

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (long i=0; i<_tagView.subviews.count; i++) {
        UILabel *tagLabel = _tagView.subviews[i];
        [tagLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [list addObject:tagLabel];
    }

    // Create the views and metrics dictionaries
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":@25.0};
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(list[0], list[1], list[2]); 

// This is experimental as I assume there are three subviews in that.

    [_tagView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[list[0]]-[list[1]]-[list[2]]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

Is this doable or do I have to take a different direction?

I forgot to add the error message I am getting:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
list is not a key in the views dictionary. 
|-[list[0]]-[list[1]]-[list[2]]-| 
       ^'
```

UPDATE:

keys seem to be fine.
[image]

Comment: Good idea. I just added the screenshot. Seems ok, no? But still doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment, becauseI tested it, and the keys were as you show. However, I think that key is causing the error because of the extra brackets. Instead of using the NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings, add keys to a mutable dictionary like label1, label2, etc inside you loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own dictionary, so the names can be added that don't have the extra brackets that you're getting now. Names like "list[0]" seem to be confusing the parser.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *views = [NSMutableDictionary new];
 NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (long i=0; i<_tagView.subviews.count; i++) {
            UILabel *tagLabel = _tagView.subviews[i];
            [tagLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            [list addObject:tagLabel];
            [views setObject:tagLabel forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%ld", i]];
        }

        NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":@25.0};

        [_tagView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[label1]-[label2]-[label3]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

Comment: Thanks, no more exceptions and I understand it too.  Now I need to find out why those labels don't appear on my screen. I suppose the rules aren't right yet.

Comment: @Houman You probably need at least on vertical constraint to one of the labels. It's not clear from your question what tagView is. Does it have constraints on it (so its size isn't zero)? You're also creating the metrics dictionary, but not doing anything with it.